# Oracle error: [: into: unknown operator

Tags: linux, oracle, shell

I m writing a shell script which connects to oracle database and executes few commands. The code looks as below.

```
mSqlCmd="select *
         from bs_transferSystemRole
         where system_ = '$system'
         and role_type = $roleType
         and abstract_type_desc = '$abstractTypeDesc'"

sqlplus -s $DB_CONNECT <<EOF 2>/dev/null
            WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
            set echo off termout off feedback off heading off
            $mSqlCmd;
            exit SQL.SQLCODE;
EOF

     if [ $? -eq 0 ]
     then
        mSQLCode=`sqlplus -s $DB_CONNECT <<EOF 2>/dev/null
            WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
            set echo off termout off feedback off heading off
            insert into bs_transferSystemRole (system_, role_type,    abstract_type_desc,use_synch_client_logic, multiple_match_option) values ('$system', $roleType, '$abstractTypeDesc','$useSyncClientLogic', $multiMatchOption);
            exit SQL.SQLCODE;
EOF`

if [ $mSQLCode -ne 0 ] // error at this line: [: into: unknown operator
        then
print "Error: Failed to add record to bs_transferSystemRole table for " \
              | tee -a $logFile
else
           print "Record for '$line' added to bs_transferSystemRole table "\
              | tee -a $logFile
fi
```

When I run the above script on a linux machine with appropriate input file, which contains all the appropriate variables in the code, I get an error [: into: unknown operator at the line if [ $mSQLCode -ne 0 ].

Is the problem with the Insert into statement in the oracle. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you add a line `echo $mSQLCode`  before the line (`if [ $mSQL..` and post the output .comment the `if else ` for a while for clarity.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I have done that and its printing the below "insert into bs_transferSystemRole (system_, role_type, abstract_type_desc,use_synch_client_logic, multiple_match_option) values ('COREIN', 67305744, '0','N', 0)"

Comment: Maybe you should add a shebang to the head of your script: `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to ensure you are getting the interpreter you expect. Also, I thought you were supposed to double quote variables like `$mSQLCode`. Finally, some semicolons seem to be missing from places I would place them, like after the closing `]` and before the `then`.

Comment: @jww Thanks for your reply. you are correct in saying that variables like $mSQLCode must be double quoted. I have modified that particular line as if [ "$mSQLCode" -ne 0 ] and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable mSQLCode in the line `if [ $mSQLCode -ne 0 ]` must be double quoted which looks as follows: `if [ "$mSQLCode" -ne 0 ]`.

The reason being mSQLCode is the result of a an Oracle query which involves multiple lines of code (`insert into ...`). The variables must be double quoted which means that multiple lines in the query must be considered.