# Getting output with [: rows: unknown operator

Tags: shell

I have this if condition shell script's piece of code, for which for true case it's working fine, for false case, output is coming but getting [: rows: unknown operator

```
ut=$(echo -ne "set heading OFF\n select user_type from usertype where acm_login = '$acmlogin';" | sqlplus -s ${ORA_UID_PSWD})
        if [ $ut != "no rows selected" ]
        then
                print "Usertype of an user $acmlogin is $ut\n"
                print "press <cr> to continue > \c"
        else
                print "Usertype not defined\n"
                print "press <cr> to continue > \c"
        fi
```

I am getting output for else part like below

```
usertype[867]: [: rows: unknown operator
Usertype not defined
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_.24foo_.3D_.22bar.22_.5D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle error: \[: into: unknown operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728829/oracle-error-into-unknown-operator)

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of explanation, let's assume the value of **ut** variable to be

```
ut = '2 rows selected'
```

During evaluation, $ut is being expanded without the double quotes so, it is equivalent to:

```
if [ $ut != "no rows selected" ]

      # is being treated by bash shell as

if [ 2 rows selected != "no rows selected" ]
```

So, the bash sees multiple arguments here. It thinks first argument is 2 and expects the second argument **rows** to be operator, hence it complains that **rows** is not an operator

A simple solution would be to **put $ut in double quotes**. So, this would solve the problem:

```
if [ "$ut" != "no rows selected" ]
```

Comment: Hi Pavan, I tried this way too.. in this case whatever the output the if condition executing only true condition getting executed even if it's false also.

Comment: Can you give an example with a value of ut variable where it is going to true condition when it should actually go to false condition?

Comment: It's like this, acmlogin = sjfkdskh(which is not presented in database) ut = no rows selected - o/p of this is -- Usertype of an user sjfkdskh is no rows selected       ----This is for false condition but getting executed true condition statements.

Comment: I think the string populated in to ut variable contains spaces or tab characters around it and so, is not exactly matching the string "no rows selected". You can change the if condition to:     `if ! echo "$ut" | grep -q "no rows selected"` This looks for the pattern rather than exact search term